# Mongoose-supported entity cannot be saved due to (mysterious) "decodeInt"/VirtualType/Getter error

Tags: node.js, mongoose, odm

I need help on saving instance of Mongoose-supported Models: Saving the entity throws the following error:

```
node.js:134
00:27:16 web.1     |         throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
00:27:16 web.1     |         ^
00:27:16 web.1     | TypeError: Cannot call method 'decodeInt' of undefined
00:27:16 web.1     |     at model.<anonymous> (.../node_modules/mongoose-types/lib/plugins/useTimestamps.js:13:37)
00:27:16 web.1     |     at VirtualType.applyGetters (.../node_modules/mongoose/lib/virtualtype.js:53:25)
00:27:16 web.1     |     at model.get (...
```

The model definition is

```
    var mongooseTypes = require("mongoose-types"), useTimestamps = mongooseTypes.useTimestamps;
mongooseTypes.loadTypes(mongoose);

var Url = mongoose.SchemaTypes.Url;

var Schema = mongoose.Schema
  , ObjectId = Schema.ObjectId;

var TextSnippetSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    text_id   : ObjectId
  , text      : String
  , context   : String
  , url       : Url
  , position  : String
});

    TextSnippetSchema.plugin(useTimestamps);
    var TextSnippet = mongoose.model('TextSnippet',TextSnippetSchema);
```

The code to create & save a new entity looks like this:

```
var instance = new TextSnippet();

   instance.text= req.query["text"];
   instance.context= req.query["ctx"];
   instance.url = req.query["url"]; 
   instance.position= "";
   console.log(JSON.stringify(instance));
   instance.save(function (err) {
       console.log(err); 
   });
```

To my understanding I have no property, where a "decodeInt" would be needed: however the entity cannot be saved.

Could you please help me to make object persistence work for me?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with mongodb not exporting BinaryParser any more.  You need to change the 
import in useTimestamps to something like this.

file
./node_modules/mongoose-types/lib/plugins/useTimestamps.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
  , ObjectID = mongoose.ObjectID
  , BinaryParser = require('mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/bson').BinaryParser;
```

and you should be good to go.  I will submit a patch to the owner for this also.

Comment: Thanks, this fix works for me.
Did you submit your patch to the owner ?

Comment: I have along with several other people with fixes, probably time to fork it.